# Powershell script to Print,Move, and then Close Adobe once complete

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that will print any PDFs that are located in the specified folder when ran. Additionally i would like for the script to move these PDFs into an Archive folder for reference after the file has been printed. Additionally the script will need to close Adobe once it is completed.

I can get the files to properly print without any attempts to move or kill the Adobe process, however if I add scripting for either of those pieces I get unsuccessful results.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem “C:\Users\bwhite\Desktop\DocsToPrint\*.pdf”

foreach ($file in $files){
    start-process -FilePath $file.fullName -Verb Print -PassThru -Wait
}

Move-Item -Path C:\Users\bwhite\Desktop\DocsToPrint\*.pdf -Destination C:\Users\bwhite\Desktop\DocsToPrint\Archive
```

Comment: What does "unsuccessful results" mean, specifically? (Remember, we can't see your screen.)

Comment: Well with how the script is listed above the first pdf will print then all the files gets moved before the remainder get to print then it hits the Wait and nothing happens. If i remove the wait then the first pdf prints and all files gets moved before they can all print.

Answer (score 0):

Sending file to a printer is a spooling action to the printspooler. The speed of the printer, will determine if the print job is done. The send to the printer is fast and the file system is done with the file and moves on to the next one.

Jobs will just queue in the spooler. You are not handling any printer activities, including print errors. You need to code for monitoring printer job success and failure before process another file.

Something like the below .
(though I did not add any error handling - I'll leave that to you)
(well, that and I am using .txt files vs Adobe)

With or without the -Wait, this works on my system as expected. Of course take out all the output message stuff if you don't want to see it. Also, Adobe will stay open, so, you need to code to kill it.

```
# Get default printer if that is the printer target
$PrinterName = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | 
ForEach { $PSItem | Where Default -eq $true }

Get-ChildItem 'D:\Temp\NewFiles\*.txt' | Select -First 3 | 
foreach {
    start-process -FilePath $PSItem.FullName -Verb Print -PassThru #-Wait

    do
    {
        # Get all print jobs on the target printer
        $PrintJobs = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue | 
        Where-Object -Property Name -eq $PrinterName.Name | 
        Select Name, JobsSpooling, Jobs, JobErrors
        Write-Warning -Message "Please wait. Printing $($PSItem.Name) now."
    }
    while ($PrintJobs.Jobs -ne 0)

    # Archive the file when the print job is complete
    $paramblock = @{
        Path = $PSItem.FullName
        Destination = 'D:\temp\Archive'
    }

    Write-Warning -Message "Printing for $($PSItem.Name) complete. Archiving the file."
    Move-Item @paramblock -Verbose
}

# Results, with the -wait, lots of message with each file printed.
<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                     
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                     
     30       5     1072       2044       0.02  19364   1 notepad                                                                         
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.txt now.
...
WARNING: Printing for TestFile0.txt complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile0.txt Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile0.txt".
     29       5      996       1880       0.00   6708   1 notepad                                                                         
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.txt now.
...
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.txt now.
WARNING: Printing for TestFile1.txt complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile1.txt Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile1.txt".
     27       4      908       1760       0.03  10108   1 notepad                                                                         
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile2.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile2.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile2.txt now.
...
WARNING: Printing for TestFile2.txt complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile2.txt Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile2.txt".
#>



# Without the -Wait, lot's of message output for the first file printed, only 3 messages for each file there after.

<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                     
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                     
     30       5     1032       1908       0.02   3704   1 notepad                                                                         
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.txt now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.txt now.
...
WARNING: Printing for TestFile0.txt complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile0.txt Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile0.txt".
     28       4      936       1788       0.00  13772   1 notepad                                                                         
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.txt now.
WARNING: Printing for TestFile1.txt complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile1.txt Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile1.txt".
     28       4      852       1700       0.00   6196   1 notepad                                                                         
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile2.txt now.
WARNING: Printing for TestFile2.txt complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile2.txt Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile2.txt".
#>
```

***Update for the OP from this.***

> I tried this making slight changes to accommodate my file paths and
>   for use with PDFs however it prints the first one immediately and i
>   received 45942 lines of the Write-Warning for the first file before i
>   stopped the script

Those message are there just for the sake of what is going on and when. They are not needed at all.

Now, all that being said, this sounds environmental.

I only say this, because as shown, what I posted works, and I did a second test by dropping a bunch of PDF files, and though I got more messages, because it take Adode time to do it's thing and send stuff to the printer, it still works.

So, Adobe is root cause of the issue, not PowerShell, when it comes to the issues you are seeing. The PDF's I created and dropped in that folder to test were the exact same content as in the text files.

***Actual Results, without using -wait:***

```
<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                     
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                     
     40       4      744       2216       0.05  18060   2 AcroRd32                                                                        
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile0.pdf now.
WARNING: Printing for TestFile0.pdf complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile0.pdf Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile0.pdf".
     49       5      796       2488       0.02   7588   2 AcroRd32                                                                        
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile1.pdf now.
WARNING: Printing for TestFile1.pdf complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile1.pdf Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile1.pdf".
     47       5      824       2532       0.00  23528   2 AcroRd32                                                                        
WARNING: Please wait. Printing TestFile2.pdf now.
WARNING: Printing for TestFile2.pdf complete. Archiving the file.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\NewFiles\TestFile2.pdf Destination: D:\temp\Archive\TestFile2.pdf".
#>
```

Each file is small (1 page - 6 lines of text or so each), having almost exactly the same content. By monitoring the print queue while this is running, you'll see how long each print job takes, this is not inclusive of the Adobe spin up an release of the file for the move.

The larger you PDF, the longer this is going to take per job. Again, only use the message for a small sample, not your production run. Remember you are literally starting Adobe each time as shown via the unique ProcessId generated.

Comment: I tried this making slight changes to accommodate my file paths and for use with PDFs however it prints the first one immediately and i received 45942 lines of the Write-Warning for the first file before i stopped the script.